# Single Page Applications using ASP Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, navigation, single-page-application

I need to implement single page applications using ASP Web Forms. I faced with a navigation problem. I need to use a navigation pattern like this:

> http:// web site url / ... / page.aspx? {query string} # {ListId} / {ItemId}

When a user request a data from the server, the request on the server doesn't contain hash # (because this is a client-side feature). And it looks like this:

> http:// web site url / ... / page.aspx? {query string}

So, actually I need two requests:

1. to get a page without hash and load javascript;
2. to handle hash data using javascript and async call required data from the server.

Is it possible to implement this logic with only one request?

Are there any best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append ListId/ItemId to query string before sending request and read it regularly on a server.

```
var url = 'http://example.com?param1=10&param2=20#1000';
var beforeHash = url.split('#')[0];
var itemId= url.split('#')[1];

var processedUrl =  beforeHash + '&itemId=' + itemId;
```

If your request is not already fired from JavaScript, you will have to hook into link's click event...

Or maybe you can get rid of `#` entirely and scroll content via JavaScript (my guess is that you use `#` because of local anchors to jump to different places in document)?

BTW There is `window.location.hash` property.

**Update**:
Based on your comment the flow is like this:

1. User types URL with #ItemId
2. Server returns the page
3. JavaScript reads #ItemId from window.location, puts it into QueryString and makes a request
4. Server returns the page based on modified QueryString

In this situation the two-requests pattern seems to be the only viable option. By design server does not get #Item part (called *fragment*). So there is no way to guess ItemId upon initial request. If after second (ajax) request, you refresh #ItemId dependant parts of the page through JavaScirpt, user experience will not be hindered much.

Comment: Thanks, I have made minor changes in my question to make it more clear. Just imagine that a user types in a browser http://...page.aspx?...#ListId/ItemId. When I handle request on the server I don't know about #ListId/ItemId. So, I need to return javascript that will put hash into querystring and sent another request. I want to know  best practices. Could you please provide links if you have?

Comment: So the flow is like this: **1**. User types URL with # **2**. Server returns the page **3**. JavaScript reads # from `window.location`, puts it into QS and makes a request **4**. Server returns the page based on modified QS?

Comment: Exactly! Are there alternatives?

Comment: Just to make things clear: do you **really** have stick with #? If you control the codebase and if it's not too expensive change you should go for second part of my answer and get rid off #. SPA's have a lot of JS so few bits of code to scroll content would not hurt.